# What is an efficient way to parallelize my loop in Visual C++ 2012? Which header: ppl.h, <thread>, <amp.h>, etc. to use?

Tags: multithreading, performance, visual-c++, c++11, parallel-processing

I am a beginner, both in C++ programming and on Stackoverflow, and I need to make my BlackJack odds simulator, which uses 1 core and 25% of my i5 CPU, run faster - ideally 3-4 times faster. 
I am overwhelmed by all the different ways of parallelizing a loop, the outermost loop in the most CPU intensive function of this program which had been working fine, albeit slowly, without paralellization. 
I am running my program on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and I tried the parallelized for loop provided by  and the concurrency library, but when I tested it out, instead of getting exactly 4 threads and 100% cpu usage like I wanted, the task manager showed the process shuffling around with different numbers of threads and different amounts of CPU usage, and it didn't perform as fast as I wanted. 
I tested out the Microsoft auto-parallelization and auto-vectorization features using the examples given on ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx ), but there were many constrains (no conditional statements, function calls, creating and assigning variables, incremental in the middle of a loop, etc) that kept me from using it, so I decided that it would probably not work out for my very complicated loop. 
Although using Microsoft's #pragma loop(hint_parallel(0)) auto-parallelization feature was super fast, automatically created exactly 4 threads, one for each core, from the start of the program and consistently made use of 100% of the CPU usage, which is what I think would be ideal - I don't think it fits my task.

Each simulation, or loop, in my program is completely independent from the rest because all the variables that the result of a simulation is based on - number of cards in the deck, number of 2's, number of 3's, etc - are the same at the end of a run of the simulation as they were at the beginning of a run of the simulation 
(if every variable and vector was not cleanly put back the way it was, an assert statement would go off). 
The only variable that is different from one iteration of the outermost loop to the next is the double "expected outcome" or "mean", and for my purposes I think I would like each element (10 elements, 1 for drawing each type of card in BlackJack valued 2 through 11) in the outermost loop to have its own "expected outcome" variable OR for the expected outcome variable to be an atomic double that is modified by different threads. 
At the end of a simulation, if there are 10 different thread local "expected outcome" variables, for initially drawing cards valued two through ace, I want that "expected outcome" variable to be returned to main and combined with the other "expected outcome" variables to get the end result - your "house edge".

So how should I go about multi-threading? 
Which library (libraries) would you make use of if you were in my position? 
Can I make 1 thread take the first value in the loop, the second thread take the second, the third thread take the third, the fourth thread take the fourth, and then have thread #1 take the fifth value in the for loop when it is finished with the first iteration of the loop? 
Should I use a fixed number of threads, or a thread pool (not that I fully understand concepts like "thread-pool" yet)? 
Should I make separate thread local variables (expected_outcome_1, expected_outcome_2) or should I use something with locks? 
Can I make automatic parallelization work in my function despite it's complexity?

One little final thing on the side. 
My original version of this program was recursive, with a function in which the dealer Draws_Card, and if dealerScore < hard17 (|| soft16) , recurse Draw_Card. 
The nice part about recursion was that the code was more compact than using a bunch of loops, although it may have been slower. 
I also found it harder to catch and fix errors in the middle of the stack than errors in the middle of a nested loop. 
And loops never accidentally went into super-deep or infinite recursion. But if I want people to read my code, having roughly 15 nested loops might not go to well, so I might want to make it tail recursive for clarity and then have the recursive calls optimized into loops. 
Would it be easy to parallelize (or auto-parallelize) a tail recursive function, as easy as it would be to parallelize a "for" loop? 
Because if so, I would hope to get rid of nested loops all together.

Comment: Fixed it. Now I just need an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea. Assume that the auto vectorization will be cyclic (each thread takes 1 loop iteration). Make an array of expected values, in which each of the 10 iterations writes to its spot in the array, i=0 through 9. After the auto-vectorized loop is done, average the 10 values in array[0] through array[9] together to get the result.

Check for dependence, then get the auto-vectorizer to do its job with a hint and then use ivdep to force the parallelization through if the compiler complains.

And forget about auto-vectorization - because there is no need to put the array values into register if they only need to be initialized and then left un-used intil after the loop is done and the theads are gotten rid of. And it's finicky and won't work if I include "if" statements, anyway.

No  library, or manually splitting a loop into threads necessary. And no graphics card computational use (yet).